# CodePen Console Blank and Google Chrome Console Displaying "Failed to Load....", Even Though No Errors Showing in Text Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, access-control, preflight, google-chrome-console

Goodmorning. I am writing JavaScript code for my Wikipedia web app, and no errors are being highlighted in the text editor, yet my CodePen console is showing blank, and my Google Chrome developer console is showing this:

(see following screenshot as well)
**OPTIONS** https://codepen.io/boomerang/iFrameKey-3deeb31e-ff4d-2d1d-6e27-aefecf3b427d/wrongfile.txt **404 ()**

**Failed to load** https://codepen.io/boomerang/iFrameKey-3deeb31e-ff4d-2d1d-6e27-aefecf3b427d/wrongfile.txt: **Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.** **Origin** 'https://s.codepen.io' **is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.**

[image: Console Errors]

See CodePen link here: https://codepen.io/IDCoder/pen/rpdBQJ?editors=1011

See JavaScript code here:

```
//JavaScript function under construction

$(document).ready(function(){ 
   //when search button is clicked, run code
   $("#search").click(function(){
     //function that gets search input(query)
     var searchTerm= $("#searchTerm").val();
     //API url with searchTerm
     var url="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search= "+ searchTerm +" &format=json&callback=?";

     $.ajax({
       type: "GET", 
       url:url,
       async: false,
       dataType:"json",
       success:function(data){
         console.log(data);
       },
       error: function(errorMessage){
         alert("error");
       }



     });

   }); //search
        function handleAjaxError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { } $.ajax({url: "wrongfile.txt", error: function(xhr){ alert("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText); }}); 

});//document ready
```

See html code here:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title> </title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="Main">
<h1>Wikepedia Viewer App</h1>
    <div class= grid-container>
        <div class="hold-everything">   

            <div class="button-1"><a href="#">Get Random Article</a>
            </div>

            <div class="input">
            <input type= "text" id="searchTerm" placeholder="Enter text....">

            </div>

            <button id ="search" type="button" class="hit-it" v>search</button>


            <div class="social-media">
                <!-- -->
                <button id ="LI" type="button" class="linkedIn">linkedIn</button>
                <button id ="FB" type="button" class="Facebook">Facebook</button>
                <button id ="TW" type="button" class="Twitter">Twitter</button>
                <button id ="EM" type="button" class="Email">Email</button>
                <!--social-media-->
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Remove the ajax call to wrongfile.txt? It's not logging to the console because there's no console log in that function, the error handler for that request is just triggering an alert and from the screenshot it looks like that's working fine.

Comment: @GraemeChapman, I just removed that ajax call, now both consoles are just blank.

Comment: @GraemeChapman, oh snap! I pressed search and it works now!!...I think maybe I had error with a capital E!